# Saving a newly created .csv file to a specific directory location/ package - Java

Tags: java, intellij-idea, filewriter, printwriter

Automating a test and need to save a csv to a certain location already wired up for the next step.

```
if (bulkJobType.equalsIgnoreCase("IP_REMOVAL")) {
            ipFileName = "IP_REMOVAL" + dtf.format(dateTimeNow) + "ip.csv";
            FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(ipFileName);
            try (PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(ipFileName))) {
                pw.write("IP_REMOVAL");
                pw.write(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
                pw.write a few other proprietary attributes
            }
```

I know 100% that this works as I have several correctly formatted unversioned files, just not in the correct place in the file structure.

File structure:

```
name
├── build
├── src
│   ├── test
│       └─java (csv creation happens in here btw)
│       └─resources
│          └─*FOLDER I WANT CSV TO SAVE IN *
│            └─IP_REMOVAL.CSV
├── *WHERE CSV IS ACTUALLY SAVING*`
```

I've tried several other stack overflow threads but can't get this to work. I find it a bit weird I can't just specify a relative path to where I want to save the newly created csv

Any help appreciated

All the other SO posts. This one
FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(new File(dir, str));

seemed the most promising but no luck

Comment: > I find it a bit weird I can't just specify a relative path to where I want to save the newly created csv --- You ARE specifying a relative path. However, it is relative to the application's user directory and that directory is not the resources directory.

Comment: > java (csv creation happens in here btw) --- No, it does not. The csv creation happens in the application's user directory. You can query the application's user directory with `System.getProperty("user.dir")`.

Comment: Note: Another term for "user directory" in this context is "working directory" or "current working directory".

Comment: It doesn't really make sense to _write_ files to the resources folder. Resources should be considered read-only. Even during testing. And that's ignoring the difference between the source directories and the build output, plus whether a class loader will see a resource created at run-time. It would make more sense to just use a temporary file that's cleaned up after the test. You can let your testing framework handle this sort of thing. E.g., if you're using JUnit 5, take a look at [TempDir](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/api/org.junit.jupiter.api/org/junit/jupiter/api/io/TempDir.html).

Comment: As an aside, if you're going to use `PrintWriter`, why not make use of its functionality? You should use [`println`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.base/java/io/PrintWriter.html#println(java.lang.String)) to write new line characters rather than `write` plus a query to the system properties.

Answer (score 1):

You can't save to the resource folder in the runtime **without specifying full path** of the local filesystem.

When you do this

```java
ipFileName = "IP_REMOVAL" + dtf.format(dateTimeNow) + "ip.csv";
```

it's equivalent of

```java
ipFileName = "<project_root>IP_REMOVAL" + dtf.format(dateTimeNow) + "ip.csv";
```

If you do try to save to the resource folder, it will be in the `target/classes/` and not in the source code resource folder that you're thinking of.

What you can do, as mentioned in the beginning, is giving full path to the resource file like `src/main/resources/folder`. Also don't forget to create directories and the file before writing to it.

Comment: Using `src/main/resources/folder` is still fragile, because it is relative to the application's user directory which you have no control over.

Comment: I agree, I discourage anyone to do this.